# Place text before and after a horizontal jquery range slider

Tags: jquery, css, rangeslider

I need to create programmatically a jquery range slider that is preceded by text and followed by text, looking something like BEFORE (range slider) AFTER. I know how to create a  element with desired width and height to hold the horizontal slider, and align the slider to the left or right edge of the window, but I can't figure out how to place the slider to the right of some existing text and then be able to add some text to the right of the slider, all on the same line. I'm probably missing something trivial.

Comment: It is not clear why you can't achieve what you wish since there is no code posted. This makes your question unclear. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
display:inline-block;
```

```css
.inline{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">This is some text</div>
<input type="range" class="inline">
<div class="inline">This is some text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks much! That fixed my problem.